# Несовпадение типов при Serializable

Tags: java, android, serializable

При попытке заменить

```
model = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key");
```

На

```
model = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
```

Мне подчеркивает строку с ошибкой о несовпадении типов мол

> Required com.project.app.Person.person

а

> Found java.io.Serializable

.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить.

Класс Model:

```
public class Model implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("products")
@Expose
private Integer products;
public String getName() {
    return name;
public Integer getProducts() {
    return products;
}
```

В адапретере передаю следующим образом

```
public void startActivity(TopStoriesAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TopStoryDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", topStoriesList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Какого класса объект `model`? Покажите этот класс.

Comment: @post_zeew обновил вопрос.

Comment: А элементы какого типа находятся в `topStoriesList`? Покажите строчку с объявлением этой переменной.

Comment: @post_zeew private List<Model> topStoriesList; c Parceable всё работало корректно, просто появилась надобность изменить на Serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы решили использовать всё таки класс `Serializable`, то начните делать по порядку:

```
Model model= new Model();
Intent i = new Intent(context, TopStoryDetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", model);
startActivity(i);
```

в `TopStoryDetailActivity.class`:

```
Model model = (Model) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
```

Ну и конечно еще раз проверьте Вашу модель, чтоб она имплементировала то что надо

```
public class Model implements Serializable {
}
```

Надеюсь будет полезным.

Comment: ошибка пропала, но как мне в putExtra вместо model, передавать `topStoriesList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());` ?

Comment: @Inkognito оставляйте Ваш метод startActivity без изменения. Должно работать. Это и есть Ваша `Model` которая хранится в topStories.