# putExtra изнутри

Tags: java, android

Было дано [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595417/220675), оно мне в принципе думаю подходит, но не было добавлено пояснение к нему. А именно меня интересует как в `putExtra` вместо `model`, передавать `topStoriesList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());` ?

Comment: Так а разве это и не есть model? Что зранится в topStoriesList?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб тогда как в данном мне решении быть со строчкой `Model model= new Model();`?

Comment: @Inkognito, `Model model = topStoriesList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());`.

Comment: @Inkognito, Если не секрет, почему Вы выбрали `Serializable` вместо `Parcelable`?

Comment: @post_zeew, на 95% уверен что потому, что так гораздо меньше лишних движений с имплиментацией всяких методов)

Comment: @post_zeew решил попробовать и этот вариант, для саморазвития) вопрос кстати решили спасибо)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну почему) есть же плагин Parceable который имплеменитрует все необходимые методы, вместо того чтобы ручками писать) а так в курсе конечно, что он намного быстрее ну и в целом лучше будет)

Comment: + если вопрос решен в другом вопросе? что делать?)

Comment: Напишите [ответ на свой вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) здесь. кнопка "Ответить на собственный вопрос" или , если вопросы идентичны, то вопрос без ответа следует закрыть, как дубликат вопроса с ответом. Дайте ссылку на вопрос, где вы получили ответ.

Comment: @pavlofff здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595417/220675 был получен ответ.